# why can't I see the form results in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner at html and I was trying to learn how forms in html works, but as shown in the below code I was not able to get the form results after clicking on submit button. Can you please tell me why its not working and how to fix it?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>html/css</title>
</head>
<body>

   <form action="result.html" method="get">
    <label for="N">Name:</label>
       <input type="text" id="N" name="Name" required>
      <br>

       <label  for="P">Phone number:</label>

       <input type="number" id="P" name="phone_nos" required> 
       <br>

    <button>submit</button>
       <br>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results"></div>
   <a href="/">Go Back</a>
    <script>
        const resultsList = document.getElementById('results')
        new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach(
(value,name)=>{ resultsList.append('${name} : ${value}')
        resultsList.append(document.createElement('br'))
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what is displayed on the screen after clicking on submit button

${name} : ${value}
${name} : ${value}

Comment: You need to use backticks if you want to use variables in a string ([Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing form method to POST instead of get

-->  `<form action="result.html" method="post">`

Comment: POST is used to send data to a server ,so we can't use that here since I have not connected to a server

Comment: Ok what I'm sure of is that GET is used to extract information from a link.